# How do I lag columns in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

i want to show NULL in all record except last record. In last record want to show previous record value.
Resultant table will be order by start_date.

i have table :

```
╔════╦══════════╦════════════╦════════════╗
║ id ║ pay_rate ║ start_date ║  end_date  ║
╠════╬══════════╬════════════╬════════════╣
║  2 ║      50  ║ 2015-08-01 ║ 2015-08-15 ║
║  4 ║      50  ║ 2015-08-16 ║ 2999-12-31 ║
║  5 ║      55  ║ 2015-07-01 ║ 2999-12-31 ║
╚════╩══════════╩════════════╩════════════╝
```

i WANT RESULT  like :

```
╔═════╦══════════════╦════════════════╦══════════════════╦══════════════╗
║ id  ║  pay_rate    ║ Pre_pay_rate   ║  pre_start_date  ║ pre_end_date ║
╠═════╬══════════════╬════════════════╬══════════════════╬══════════════╣
║ 5   ║ 50           ║ NULL           ║ NULL             ║ NULL         ║
║ 2   ║ 50           ║ NULL           ║ NULL             ║ NULL         ║
║ 4   ║ 55           ║ 50             ║ 2015-08-01       ║ 2015-08-15   ║
╚═════╩══════════════╩════════════════╩══════════════════╩══════════════╝
```

Thanks in Advance :-)

Comment: so what you have attempted so far? If everything has to be null except the very last record, why not just add that data yourself once you've fetched the data into your client?

Comment: I am confused by this - in your example the id changes for start/end date between the original table & the required result.

Comment: @Marc B this query was used in view along with other records add latter and that many other views are depend on this view.

Comment: @PaulF The data isnt order by date, the result is.

Comment: PaulF yes the records are displayed as order by start_date

Comment: In your result ... your not `NULL` values are the first row? because in your question you say you want the previous row

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza i want previous row records value in last tuple only remaining will be shown as NULL

Comment: Your comment doesnt match your sample/result data can you explain it a litle more. please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
   And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

this is a great place to start  http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Even after the edits - I can't see how the result relates to the original data - the id numbers are now ordered by date order. But id 5 had a pay rate of 55 in the original data & now has 50, id 4 had pay rate 50 & now has 55.

Comment: @PaulF you are right that is my mistake Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Long winded & there may be a better solution but this gets the results you want.

First part of the query selects all but the last record, by sorting in reverse order, skipping the first record & then resorting in date order. The the second part selects the final record & joins it to the previous record.

```
SELECT id, pay_rate, pre_payrate, pre_start_date, pre_end_date FROM 
(SELECT * FROM (SELECT id, pay_rate, start_date, NULL pre_payrate, NULL pre_start_date, NULL pre_end_date
FROM mytable
ORDER BY start_date DESC
LIMIT 1, 9223372036854775807) alias1 ORDER BY start_date) alias2
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT id, pay_rate
FROM mytable
ORDER BY start_date DESC 
LIMIT 1) alias3
JOIN
(SELECT pay_rate pre_payrate, start_date pre_start_date, end_date pre_end_date
FROM mytable
ORDER BY 1 DESC 
LIMIT 1,1) alias4
```

NOTE - start_date needs including in the first query so it can be used to put the query back into the correct date order. 9223372036854775807 is biggest signed int.

Comment: right now i am not able to UP the vote but i would love to UP the vote many times. Thanks Again :-)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza yes!!